# Couldn't find sql server agent in Sql Server 2014 Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

Is there any way to add it in SQL Server Express edition?

Comment: Expression edition doesn't include this feature. You can sess SQL Server Agent service but cant start it. you can use windows task scheduler in place of SQL Server agent

Comment: You need to know what features are available with which version. Express edition has limitations. Have a good look at those..You will need to use the Task Scheduler for scheduling anything in Express edition.

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot have SQL Server agent feature in express edition of SQL Server. To get that you would have to upgrade to licensed version of SQL Server like Enterprise, Standard, Web and Developer editions. Just so that you know you can see the SQL Server agent services in express edition but that cannot be started.
If you want to use scheduling to schedule jobs you have to rely in windows scheduler

[From SQL Server 2014 onwards the developer edition is free to download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/) and use and this version has SQL Server agent feature. The only limitation is you cannot use developer version in production, you can ONLY use it in development and testing environment.

Answer (score 2):

There is no SQL Agent included in SQL Server Express. You'll need to find a different way to schedule jobs unless you switch to a different edition of SQL Server.

Other options include:

- Using Task Scheduler
- Third party software, like [JAMS Scheduler](http://www.jamsscheduler.com/job-scheduling/) which has a community version free for 1 year with 50 job runs/day (no affiliation)
- Develop something custom
- Run the jobs manually :)

References:

- Microsoft KB: [How to schedule and automate backups of SQL Server databases in SQL Server Express](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019698/how-to-schedule-and-automate-backups-of-sql-server-databases-in-sql-se)
- expressdb.io: [SQL Express vs Standard Feature Comparison for 2014](http://expressdb.io/sql-server-express-feature-comparison/#sql-2014) *(I own this site)*
- MS Docs: [SQL 2014 Edition Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc645993%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- MSSQLTips: [Centralized SQL Server Job Management with JAMS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3158/centralized-sql-server-job-management-with-jams-job-scheduler/)

Comment: Which feature in the Developer installation contains the SQL Agent? I don't want to install all features since I only need the Agent.

Comment: It will be installed by default

Comment: I found out that you only need to install the first/top feature "Database Engine Services". You can leave all other features unchecked which saves you a ton of Gigabytes.

Answer (score 1):

**SQL server 2014 express does not have SQL Server agent**, only available on Standard and Enterprise editions. You can take help from **creating batch files and running them through CMD**, **Windows scheduler** will let you schedule it.

Here are [Features supported by the different editions of SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).ASPX#Mgmt_tools)

Comment: SQL Server agent feature is also available in Web and BI editions.